# Can I find the index of an occurrence of an Outlook appointment pattern

Tags: outlook-redemption

I use Redemption to go through some recurring appointments in Outlook and I can get the changed/deleted occurrences of these recurring appointments via the `RDORecurrencePattern.Exceptions` property.

What I really want to find out, is the index of these modified occurrences in the entire recurring series, this is the same index `RDORecurrencePattern.GetOccurence(Index)` uses to find the occurrence.

But it doesn't look like this property is exposed anywhere. Does anyone know any way to find this index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a property is not exposed unfortunately. The best you can do is loop through all occurrences and open each occurrence using `RDORecurrencePatterm.GetOccurence` passing an integer index, you can then compare the start date of the occurrence with the date of the given exception.

Comment: It's a pity but if this is the only way then I guess I'll have to go down the path. Thanks Dmitry.